# Assembly typing number and print string

Tags: assembly

I am using EMU8086 and i am trying to make a program which takes a number I type and prints its name (type 1 print one).I Any suggestions?
This is my code unil now bit it keeps printing "one" .

```
.data


buffer1 db 'one',0Dh,0Ah,'$'
buffer2 db 'two',0Dh,0Ah,'$'


.code
start: 
mov ax,@data
mov dx,ax
mov es,ax


next:
mov ah,08h
int 21h
cmp al,'1'
jz one
cmp al,'0'
jz two
jmp next



one:

lea dx,buffer1
mov ah,09h
int 21h
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
jmp end

two:

lea dx,buffer2
mov ah,09h
int 21h
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
jmp end


end:

.exit
end start
```

Comment: `cmp al,'0'`, shouldn't that be `cmp al,'2'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov ah,08h
int 21h
```

21H/08H doesn't exist.
to INPUT a String it's 21H/0AH.
hope that will work :)

Comment: Of course it does exist! The OP haven't asked for input of a string. But it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: i meant to input a string it's 0AH :)